# Adam lay ybounden. Any ys around these days?

Tags: prefixes, archaicisms, historical-change

Thanks for pointing out the similar question. Great, but note that I'm trying to find ...

• is there any SPECIFIC examples/evidence around of yword yusage TODAY?

• other than jokey usage, is there any fresh and real usage?

• nobody has explained, simply what period was it popular? (if at all - or was it just an artifact or something?)

• and indeed, what ywere the Top Three Yword greatest hits?

Cheers!

---

I made an ybounden the other day,

[image]

and it brought to mind the questions:

These days, are there any words which use the y- prefix?

What is the origin of this prefix?

In what period was it popular?

What were, at that time, other popular words with the y- prefix?

Is it perhaps today still popular in other (European?) languages - which?

Is the whole thing just a typo/artifact? What's the deal?

But mostly ........ are there any ywords popular today?

Comment: I occasionally use *yclept*, 'cause I'm a jerk.

Comment: Among hundreds of Middle English words it formed are yfallen, yhacked ("completely hacked," probably now again useful), yknow, ymarried, ywrought. (Etymonline)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What we've gelost — why doesn't English use the prefix "ge-"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22700/what-weve-gelost-why-doesnt-english-use-the-prefix-ge) Per [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/231077), *[the **y-** prefix] represents Old English **ge-**, earlier (and Northumb.) **gi-**,* etc., etc.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/232693/14666

Comment: @DanBron 'cause you're a yjerk

Comment: @Kris So I've been ytold.

Comment: @DanBron I don't think I've ever used "yclept" but it was the first thing that came to mind when I read the question. Do I qualify as a jerk?

Comment: To see those Y words in action, read *The Canterbury Tales* in the original language, of course.

Comment: @JoeBlow 1. http://www.americanthinker.com/blog/2016/04/a_looming_moral_dilemma.html  2. ACRONYM stands for Alphabetically Condensed Representation of Neologically Yclept Magniloquence https://www.allacronyms.com/ACRONYM/Alphabetically_Condensed_Representation_of_Neologically_Yclept_Magniloquence   ...

Comment: ... 3. "And IBM, yclept Dr. Watson, an Aesculapian bean-counter enlightened by AI, is injecting itself into medicine. As the temperance folk asked after banishing demon rum, "What could go wrong?"" http://www.itjungle.com/tfh/tfh072715-story04.html 4. https://pjmedia.com/diaryofamadvoter/2015/12/30/sex-lies-clinton-and-trump/  5. http://www.nationalmemo.com/bernie-sanders-meets-pope-in-vatican-city/ AND all these in the past year alone.

Comment: 1) For usage nowadays, no, 'y-' is not used at all as a prefix for past participle (or for any prefix). 2) For the time span: OE used 'ge-', ME used 'y-' or not at all, EME use 'y-' very rarely ('yclept').

Comment: that's a pretty decisive answer, @Mitch, perhaps it would be ywise to put it in?

Comment: @JoeBlow As annoyed as people might be by an answer in a comment, that comment is essentially what is answered at the duped question. I just don't like anyone to go away upset for being closed. Also, yusing one omre 'y-' to yprefix everything is going to make me ybarf... _ybleurgh_

Comment: I just want to say I've really enjoyed this question and the answers. I would've answered it myself if Mitch hadn't come through. :D

Comment: So that's where *y|know* is from, you know?

Comment: LOL good one, @vectory.  Y'all know that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many of your questions are answered tangentially by [What we've gelost — why doesn't English use the prefix "ge-"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22700/what-weve-gelost-why-doesnt-english-use-the-prefix-ge). But you ask some new questions about current usage.

- For usage nowadays in all varieties of Modern English, no, none of 'y-', 'ge-', or their derivatives are used at all as a prefix for past participle (or for any prefix). It might appear modified in some ossified phrases or words (eg [handiwork](https://www.etymonline.com/word/handiwork), or in rare regionalisms as 'a-'.
- 'ge-' is entirely a Germanic past participle marker (it appears in *no* other Indo-European language (sumelic will surely correct me here if otherwise)) and has been lost in many Germanic ones as well (enumerated in other answers here).
- For the time span: OE (up to 1066) used 'ge-', ME (~1150 - ~1500) used 'y-' or not at all, EModE use 'y-' very rarely ('yclept'), and Modern Standard English never. (all dates extremely vague and labels oversimplified!). There may be various holdovers in regional dialects. But note that the descendents of 'ge-' would have to be past participles; "Froggy's gone acourtin'" is an entirely different anachronistic 'a-', not from 'ge-'.
- the top three archaic words that are sometimes used are ['yclept' for 'called'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yclept), 'yclad' for 'clothed', ... and .. really, 'ybounden'? I've never heard that outside the hymn (and even then the memory is pretty hazy (end even then I don't really know what it means)). As to popularity, sure, some people use 'yclept' in a faux medieval cant, along with 'methinks', 'betwixt', and 'ye'.

What's really a word? It's obvious when it is and obvious when it isn't, but near the borderline it's not obvious. If it is in your Scrabble dictionary... sigh ... that's a game that *has* to have arbitrary rules. Sure, go wild and use 'y-' in Scrabble (if your reference dictionary allows), at your local Renaissance Fayre, or to signal to your local Morris Dancing group that you are kindred spirits. Just recognize the use as very ... particular.

Also, the OED (use your local US/UK library site to connect, sorry everyone else) has an excellent entry on 'y-' (prefix 2), and answers all these questions in depth. Note that that entry has no citations, implying that it is ... not really a thing anymore.

Comment: LOL and excellent. :)  Say, what about "a-wooing" mentioned by New User amanda?

Comment: @Fattie That was covered in pt three about timing; the 'a-' in 'a-X-ing' is not from 'y-' but from 'on'. To be a descendent of 'ge-', the rest of the verb needs to be a past participle.

Comment: Gotchya - awesome.  Sorry i missed that.

Comment: *Betwixt* is hardly medieval!!!

Comment: *Ybounden* does actually mean *bound:* the carol affirms that Adam (mankind) was bound by sin until freed by Christ, whose coming was necessary because of the original sin of taking the apple.

Comment: @AndrewLeach oh sure, It's not too hard to figure out. But it sure is unexpected.

Comment: Enjoy that bounty!    (It's good to see new users without many points getting a start right?    :-)  )

Answer (score 6):

The closest examples are with the prefix "a-" in the likes of "a frog he would a-wooing go", which is from "ge-", and the "I" in "handiwork", also from "ge-".  The meaning of "ge-" in Old English wasn't ybounden to the verb or universal as it is nowadays in German, although that also has other examples too, but is more a sense of being completed or gathered together, as with "ywis" - certainly, so the "i" is a valid example.

Comment: Welcome new user.  That is a fantastic example - THANKS

Comment: As said here, "closest ..."  Do note @Mitch 's answer though.

Answer (score 3):

To see those Y words in action, read The Canterbury Tales in the original language, of course.  published 1386

For example, line 1149, in *The Knyghtes Tale*,

> For which thou art ybounden as a knyght

As explained in a more complete answer, if you know that in German the past participle is formed with prefix *ge-*, then you can recognize the similarity with these past participles formed in Chaucer's English with *y-*.

[image: pic]

In this picture, we can see the line

> That whilom was ycleped Scithia,

Answer (score 1):

shorter Oxford Eng Dict lists 4 yclad, yclept, ypent, ywroken but are all described as archaic. It also includes a dozen obsolete y- words which apparently derive from the germanic→Old Englsih words with the prefix ge- (and are perhaps identical to the latin co-). Did you really mean to call English a Romance language??? Same source says most of those words were lost by the late Middle English period, but some survived as intentional archaicisms and mentions the above two as well as yravish. Here is the one's I spotted:yblent, yborn, ybound, ybrent, yclepped, ydred, yfere, ygo, ypight, ysame, ysprung, ywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think there are words where Y as prefix replaced Ge  and still very very much currently in use:

> **YES**

Middle English, from Old English gēse
Old English gēse, from iā sīe meaning **may it be**;

and also

> **YEA**

Old English **gē a**; related to Old Frisian jē, Old Saxon, Old Norse, Old High German jā, Gothic jai

and for the third one

> **YOU**

**
Old English ēow, dative and accusative of gē ye;

Definitions taken form [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/yea) and [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yes)

Comment: It seems to me the "ge/y" in all of these words is completely unrelated to the prefix in "ybounden."

Comment: it seems to me that they are:Y denote the completion of something, as in a verb on participle, here from the verb Be,   yes= so be it/it's done/indeed . For Gea =Yea = "completely always" It's more disputable for you. But I may be wrong.

Comment: The prefix "ge/y" that denotes completion is reconstructed as Proto-Germanic [ga-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/ga-), thought to be from Proto-Indo-European kom-. "Yes"/"yea" are from a separate root, reconstructed as Proto-Germanic [ja](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/ja). "You" is from yet another root, Proto-Germanic [jūz/izwiz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/jūz). Consider that the German prefix *ge-*  which is cognate to the English prefix *y-* is not used with the words "ja" (yes) and "ihr" (you).

Comment: That's why I say that they don't seem related. The word "you" just does not have a prefix. "Yes" and "yea" may have originated as compound words, but the first word in these compounds is unrelated to the "y-" prefix found in "ybounden."

Comment: Compare Ger. *genau* "exactly", apparently \*ge- + \*nou(we), used in place of *ja* occasionally; And *genug* "enough", cognate ME *ynough*, OE *genog*, from \*ge- + \*nogaz.

Comment: @sumelic, consider that g~j is a Low German dialectical variation and compare southern Ger. "gell?" "yea?", related to *gelten* "to be valid", which is acceptable, but only moves the problem there with *Geld* "money", and *yield*, etc, which is considerable if comparing "Gehalt". *Geld* has only Germanic and Slavic cognates in Pokorny, while the root \*ghel- found elsewhere doesn't explain much and is obviously comparable to variations with k, cp. *call* and *yell*. I think I'm trying to say that PGem \*ja might be wrong or not all the story, compared to the weird Fr *oui*. Also see *gay*.